# Swift: Convert Float array to array of structs

Tags: arrays, swift

I've an array of floats

```
var ar = [Float]()

for (var i=0; i<900; i++) {
    ar.append(Float(i))
}
```

How can I convert the above array to an array of structs of type:

```
struct Vec {
    var x: Float
    var y: Float
    var z: Float
}
```

Without iterating through the first array?

an example equivalent in C/C++ might be something like this:

```
memmove(&vecBuf[0], floatBuf, 900 * sizeof(float));
```

Comment: You can't. One way or another, you _must_ iterate through the array to do this. Even if you could use `map` to perform the conversion, `map` would be iterating. What do you have against iterating? What's the alternative: magic?

Comment: Also, how would you "convert"? Do you want `ar[0]` to become the first `x`, `ar[1]` to become the first `y`, and so forth? Or what? You haven't even specified the _problem_.

Comment: That is totally possible in C/C++, that's why I'm wondering. Basically speed is the issue. I have arrays that hold more than 600k elements so it takes long to iterate.

Comment: Then do it in C! No problem.

Comment: Actually the float array is coming from a C function and I want to pass it to Swift in meaningful structures. The main part of the software is made with swift and a few time critical ops in C. Unless you mean to rewrite the whole software in C.. Not an efficient answer I would say.

Comment: C structs arrive in Swift as Swift structs. So if you think it's so magically efficient, convert to structs in C and pass them into Swift.

Comment: I don't think that a struct in C will arrive as the same type as an existing struct used throughout the code even if it has the same name and fields. Anyway thanks for you help. I guess it's not possible. Will have to look into other options.

Comment: You don't? How on earth do you imagine this code works: `let sz = CGSizeMake(200,300)` ?

Comment: If you have an array of GLKVector3 in swift, and you define a struct in C called GLKVector3, even though they have the same name and properties you can't add it to the first array defined in Swift. You would have to convert it.

Comment: True. But if you define a struct in C called GLKVector3, you can receive such a struct from C into Swift and it will simply _be_ a Swift struct called GLKVector3. Moreover, you can _extend_ GLKVector3 within Swift (e.g. give it initializers, methods, etc.). Again, look at how CGSize and CGRect work. - And see my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_c_structs

Comment: Yes thats true, but the software already uses GLKVector3 in a million ways. If I wanted to move that to C, I would have to rewrite the whole GLKMath library in C (or use something like GLM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think `memmove` is reasonable, then you will probably prefer this very Swifty way:

```
// assume ar is a [Float] variable
var mem = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.alloc(ar.count)
mem.initializeFrom(ar)
var mem2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Vec>(mem)
```

In that version, we simply start with a buffer version of your Float array and *regard* it as a Vec array.

Comment: Yes! This works even faster than memmove. I can't seem to get it working with C arrays yet because of type casting errors but that shouldn't be hard.  Thanks Matt!
BTW: Timing of memmove was 0.32015 sec for 900k float elements
and with the above solution it was 0.00254 sec's

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I can use memcpy/memmove in Swift the same way as in C

```
struct Vec {
    var x: Float
    var y: Float
    var z: Float
}

var ar = [Float]()

for (var i=0; i<900; i++) {
    ar.append(Float(i))
}

var res = [Vec](count: 300, repeatedValue:Vec(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0))

memmove(&res, ar, sizeof(Float) * ar.count)

NSLog("%f %f %f \n", res[0].x, res[0].y, res[0].z)
```

memmove compared to iterating the large float array and converting to structures resulted in more than 5 seconds less (when float array length was ~560.000).

Comment: Why is that a solution? You iterate _twice_. Did you do any timing tests on it?

Comment: What do you mean I iterate twice? Where?

Comment: I hope you don't mean the 'for' loop that creates a test array of Float! really?? According to you there was no way to do it, and here it is.. The only line from the above test case you should emphasise is "memmove(&res, ar, sizeof(Float) * ar.count)" which replaces iterating the float array and creating structs of type Vec.

Comment: No, I mean the call to `count:repeatedValue:` and the call to `memmove` - especially the former.

Comment: I'm sure there are other ways to initialise the bounds of the array, I just used that for testing purposes but it turns out its very fast. Less then 0.02 seconds for an array of 500.000. Memmove does not iterate, it just copies the memory from one buffer to another. Again very very fast.